# Best Way to do Columns in HTML/CSS

Tags: html, css

I'm looking for a way to display 3 columns of content. I've found a way to display wrap-around columns, but I don't want that for this page. I'm looking for a way to say

```
<column>
<!-- content -->
</column>
```

3 times, and have 3 columns displayed beside each other. The best example I have offhand is The Verge (http://www.theverge.com/). What is the best way to do this?

Comment: Use float in your stylesheet?

Comment: Hate to say it but sometimes just using the old school table element is the easiest way to format content in rows and columns.  I know you are looking for a css route so decided to add comment rather than answer.

Comment: @TheJumpingFrog I've used float but I find inconsistent behaviour with this depending on screen size. Is there a way to say "always display in this one format" using the float method?

Comment: @DanP I'm currently trying tables also, but I'm having issues getting them centered (for whatever reason, the bootstrap CSS might be messing it up) so I figured I'd look elsewhere before fighting with a table further.

Comment: @rar: to center the tables, you can use this in CSS: table { margin: auto; width: 100%; }

Comment: Also, for the float, you should set their widths to 33% (if 3 columns)

Comment: They should also be centered. Would `.column { float:left; margin:auto; width:33% }` work for that?

Comment: Twitter bootstrap is not working for you? (http://twitter.github.com/bootstrap/base-css.html#tables). It should add media queries to keep your table looking good even if you change your browser's window.

Comment: That's for data tables though. I was trying to use the table for layout.

Comment: Here is a good explanation for two columns http://codenuggets.com/2014/05/22/css-two-column-layout/

Answer (score 42, accepted):

I would suggest you to either use `<table>` or CSS.

CSS is preferred for being more flexible. An example would be:

```
<!-- of course, you should move the inline CSS style to your stylesheet -->
<!-- main container, width = 70% of page, centered -->
<div id="contentBox" style="margin:0px auto; width:70%">

 <!-- columns divs, float left, no margin so there is no space between column, width=1/3 -->
    <div id="column1" style="float:left; margin:0; width:33%;">
     CONTENT
    </div>

    <div id="column2" style="float:left; margin:0;width:33%;">
     CONTENT
    </div>

    <div id="column3" style="float:left; margin:0;width:33%">
     CONTENT
    </div>
</div>
```

jsFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/ndhqM/

Using float:left would make 3 columns stick to each other, coming in from left inside the centered div "content box".

Comment: I think you want that `width` inside the style attribute: `style="margin:0 auto; width: 70%;"`. Also, I'm not aware of any browsers that apply margin to `div` in their default style sheet, so `margin: 0;` on the floated divs would seem superfluous.

Comment: I want to add that I found Mikey's answer was required for my personal formatting issues. Future readers, see Mikey's answer as well as this one.

Comment: You also have CSS Grid and CSS Flex, both can give you columns that keep their position and size ratios depending on screen size, and flex can also easily rearrange the columns if screen size is too small so they can maintain a minimum width nicely. see https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/complete-guide-grid/ and https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/

Answer (score 25):

You should probably consider using css3 for this though it does include the use of vendor prefixes.

I've knocked up a quick [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/QP3vx/) to demo but the crux is this.

```
<style>
.3col
{
    -webkit-column-count: 3;
    -webkit-column-gap: 10px;
    -moz-column-count: 3;
    -moz-column-gap: 10px;
    column-count:3;
    column-gap:10px;
}
</style>
<div class="3col">
<p>col1</p>
<p>col2</p>
<p>col3</p>
</div>
```

Comment: You may find it useful to know the browser support on this on [w3schools](http://www.w3schools.com/css3/css3_multiple_columns.asp); IE10+. I have to wait for better browser support

Comment: @Duncanmoo's link is broken, try this one: http://caniuse.com/multicolumn - currently only about 14% of browser support by usage (76% with prefixes).

Comment: Wish I could edit an old comment, well here is the browser support on this on [w3schools](http://www.w3schools.com/css/css3_multiple_columns.asp) link.

Comment: Cool stuff! Exactly what I needed!

Comment: It's quite broadly supported now (≈83%). Take a look at [caniuse](http://caniuse.com/multicolumn/embed/) for browser support.

Comment: [97.8% browser support](https://caniuse.com/#search=columns) now. Check more about columns option in CSS [here](https://kolosek.com/css-columns/)

Answer (score 9):

In addition to the 3 floated column structure (which I would suggest as well), you have to insert a clearfix to prevent layoutproblems with elements after the columncontainer (keep the columncontainer in the flow, so to speak...).

```
<div id="contentBox" class="clearfix">
....
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.clearfix { zoom: 1; }
.clearfix:before, .clearfix:after { content: "\0020"; display: block; height: 0; overflow: hidden; }
.clearfix:after { clear: both; }
```

Comment: You're welcome. Keep in mind that this is the common way to fix layout problems with floated elements (like `ul` menus)

Comment: I'll definitely make note of that, since it's not the first time I've run into issues with this. Thanks!

Comment: Using clearfix is very common, however if you have a wrapper around the three columns, you can set that wrapper (#contentBox in this case) to overflow:auto;. This will make the #contentBox expand to accomodate the three columns, regardless of their height, thus pushing the below content, down. It's a much cleaner solution and requires less classes in the HTML.

Comment: @PatrikAlienus Thats a great tip. However, using overflow: auto will put scroll bar on the #contentBox div. You could use overflow hidden instead or set height to the child nodes.

Comment: @SrikanthKondaparthy True there are some instances where scrollbars may appear - in some browsers. However there are usually ways around it. 'overflow:hidden' would however hide the floated divs, so I don't really see how that would solve it?.. Setting the height is always an option - if you know the height. With dynamic content that's not a solution either.

Answer (score 4):

You might also try.

```css
.col{
  float: left;
}
.col + .col{
  float: left;
  margin-left: 20px;
}

/* or */

.col:not(:nth-child(1)){
  float:left;
  margin-left: 20px;
}
```

```html
<div class="row">
  <div class="col">column</div>
  <div class="col">column</div>
  <div class="col">column</div>
</div>
```

ref: http://codepen.io/co0kie/pen/gPKNWX?editors=1100

Answer (score 2):

Bootstrap. Check out their awesome grid system [here](http://getbootstrap.com/css/).

Using Bootstrap, you could make three columns like this:

```
<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-4">.col-md-4</div>
    <div class="col-md-4">.col-md-4</div>
    <div class="col-md-4">.col-md-4</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want to do multiple (3+) columns here is a great snippet that works perfectly and validates as valid HTML5:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <title>Multiple Colums</title>

        <!-- Styles -->
        <style>
            .flex-center {
                width: 100%;
                align-items: center;/*These two properties center vetically*/
                height: 100vh;/*These two properties center vetically*/
                display: flex;/*This is the attribute that separates into columns*/
                justify-content: center;
                text-align: center;
                position: relative;
            }
            .spaceOut {
                margin-left: 25px;
                margin-right: 25px;
            }
        </style>

    </head>
    <body>
        <section class="flex-center">
            <h4>Tableless Columns Example</h4><br />
            <div class="spaceOut">
                Column 1<br />
            </div>
            <div class="spaceOut">
                Column 2<br />
            </div>
            <div class="spaceOut">
                Column 3<br />
            </div>      
            <div class="spaceOut">
                Column 4<br />
            </div>
            <div class="spaceOut">
                Column 5<br />
            </div>
        </section>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Getting rid of `align-items: center;` stops the column headers from being pushed down.

Answer (score 1):

You also have CSS Grid and CSS Flex, both can give you columns that keep their position and size ratios depending on screen size, and flex can also easily rearrange the columns if screen size is too small so they can maintain a minimum width nicely.

See these guides for full details:

- https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/complete-guide-grid/
- https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox

Grid:

```
.container {
  display: grid | inline-grid;
}
```

Flex:

```
.container {
  display: flex | inline-flex;
}
```