# Align Text with Indent

Tags: html, css, responsive-design

Is it possible to align text with indent over multiple lines and responsible?
Like two Columns which breaks when the window ist too small.

**For Example:**

When Content fits in one Line:

```
Text        Value
Longer Text Value
Text        Longer Value
```

When Content does not fit in one Line:

```
Text
Value

Longer Text
Value

Text
Longer Value
```

---

The first text should so long it needs, so I don't wan't extra space behind it.

Here is a example where I have a fixed length of the text "column":

```css
dt {
  width: 6em; //I want a solution without a width
  display: inline-grid;
}

dt,
dd {
  float: left
}

dt {
  clear: both
}
```

```html
<dl>
  <dt>Text</dt>
  <dd>Value</dd>
  <dt>Longer Text</dt>
  <dd>Value</dd>
  <dt>Text</dt>
  <dd>Longer Value</dd>
</dl>
```

So I want the same result without setting the min-width or width of the text "column".

Comment: Can't you just make them 2 columns?

Comment: Do you have any code that you tried?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Best Way to do Columns in HTML/CSS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9966890/best-way-to-do-columns-in-html-css)

Comment: @Huangism columns wouldn't be responsive and break

Comment: @Tilo any responsive site you see is done by having code in the background making it responsive. Take a look at media queries https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Media_Queries/Using_media_queries

Comment: @Tijmen no solution works like I want. They only has the one row aspect or not doing a dynamic length of the columns.

Comment: @Huangism you think I should make a table and a media query for the break machnism? Then media query has to be dynamic for each set of a list, becouse every list has another length which it should break.

Comment: @Tilo your example shows big window 2 col and small window 1 col and does not mention anything about the actual content. Your big/small window would be where media query comes in. As for the content, you are going to have to give some examples

Comment: @schylake I added a code example.

Comment: @Huangism I edited my post, so that you could understand my problem better.

Comment: @Tilo yea ok so it's just media query but the media query will apply to all of your lists.

Answer (score 0):

Misunderstood your first question. This styling would adjust based on screen-size. You'll want to assign your element style names as using just this would mess up your page.

```
.lineTitle{
  width: 6em;
  display:block;
  font-weight:bold;
}
.yourList  {margin-bottom:10px; }

@media (min-width:768px){
.lineTitle {display: inline;}
  .yourList  {margin-bottom:0px; }
}
```

UPDATED: You just need to wrap them in spans and name them.

```
 <div>
  <div class="yourList">
    <span class="lineTitle">Text</span>
    <span class="lineValue">Value</span>
  </div>
   <div class="yourList">
    <span class="lineTitle">Text</span>
    <span class="lineValue">Value</span>
  </div>
  <div class="yourList">
    <span class="lineTitle">Text</span>
    <span class="lineValue">Longer Value</span>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Can you make a example with my added example?

Comment: Edited to correlate with your new code. The columns I mentioned before were unnecessary.

Comment: I want an universal code, so without the width in the b tag.

Comment: Updated to be controlled without the b tag.

Answer (score 0):

CSS "column-count" can achieve this, but if the text and value pairs are related, a definition list would be more semantic:

```
<dl>
    <dt>Text</dt>
    <dd>Value</dd>
    <dt>Longer Text</dt>
    <dd>Value</dd>
    <dt>Text</dt>
    <dd>Longer Value</dd>
</dl>
```

With a media query you can also change the layout for smaller vs larger screen sizes.

Working example here: https://codepen.io/code-and-pixels/pen/WZKKgE

Comment: The Problem in your solution is that the width of the dt is fixed to 150px and not dynamic.

Comment: That's just an example -- the width could be set to any relative unit of measure (%, em, etc.). There was no specific design or layout context provided so I threw that in.

Comment: I want an universal Code where I have to set no width. So I can use it with smaller and longer texts.

Comment: You're unlikely to find a solution without any width setting at all. A width setting just provides layout context -- without it the width will be set for each pair based on what the content is. That's not really acceptable in most UI situations.

I mean, it sounds like you want to use a old school table for layout. That's ill advised for so many reasons, but your no-width-but-still-in-a-single-column requirement is limiting.